# String sort on basis of length and then on basis of case

Tags: java, string

I am trying to sort a list of String which sorts on the basis of both length as well as Case Sensitivity.

Example : 
Before Sort:[a, abc, b, fe, e, ABC, Abc]

After Sort :[a, b, e, fe, abc, Abc, ABc, ABC]

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("a");
    stringList.add("abc");
    stringList.add("b");
    stringList.add("fe");
    stringList.add("e");
    stringList.add("ABC");
    stringList.add("Abc");
    stringList.add("ABc");

    System.out.print("Before Sort:");
    System.out.println(stringList);

    Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator<String>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if(o1.length() > o2.length())
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if(o1.length() < o2.length()){
                    return -1;
                }
                else if(o1.length() == o2.length()){
                    return return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
                else return 0;
        }
    });
    System.out.print("After Sort :");
    System.out.println(stringList);
}
```

Above code sorts the list on the basis of length,but fails to sort on the basis of Case Sensitivity.

It Gives the ouput,
[a, b, e, fe, ABC, ABc, Abc, abc]

Expected Output 
After Sort :[a, b, e, fe, abc, Abc, ABc, ABC]

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to consider more cases like `A`, `Fe`, `fE`. It seems your sorting does not have a natural flow. The code below gets the output you want.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaApplication114
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("a");
        stringList.add("abc");
        stringList.add("b");
        stringList.add("fe");
        stringList.add("e");
        stringList.add("ABC");
        stringList.add("Abc");
        stringList.add("ABc");

        System.out.print("Before Sort:");
        System.out.println(stringList);

        Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2)
            {
                if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (o1.length() == o2.length()) {
                    if (o1.length() == 1) {
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }
                    else {
                        return o2.compareTo(o1);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.print("After Sort :");
        System.out.println(stringList);
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
run:
Before Sort:[a, abc, b, fe, e, ABC, Abc, ABc]
After Sort :[a, b, e, fe, abc, Abc, ABc, ABC]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
return o1.toLowerCase().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.toLowerCase())
```

contradicts your specs. You shouldn't be comparing with ignore case and transforming in lowercase if you want to have case sensititve ordering.

Answer (score 2):

'a' > 'A' in natural order. If you want to sort your strings in descending order then change `o1.compareTo(o2);` to `o2.compareTo(o1);` As a side note you can use `Integer.compare(int x, int y)` to get rid of the repeated if else. Example:

```
    Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int comp = Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
            if (comp == 0) {
                return o1.length()==1 ? o1.compareTo(o2):o2.compareTo(o1);
            } 
             return comp;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @slider_rahul Missed the natural order for strings with length = 1. Edited.